# How can i write with for()

Tags: javascript

```js
var honap = ['Január', 'Február', 'Március', 'Április', 'Május', 'Június', 'Július', 'Augusztus', 'Szeptember', 'Október', 'November', 'December'];
var nap = ['V', 'H', 'K', 'Sze', 'Cs', 'P', 'Szo'];
var currentyear = new Date();
var ev = currentyear.getFullYear();
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("napok2").innerHTML = ev + "." + honap[d.getMonth()];
```

```html
<div id='napok2'></div>
```

Can I write somehow with for() the months of the year, last year, and the after 3 years? Like `2019.januar, 2019.februar... etc, to 2023.december`

Comment: I would highly recomment showing us what you have tried so far...  There are tons of examples on the internet about for loops in Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
    var honap = ['Január', 'Február', 'Március', 'Április', 'Május', 
    'Június', 'Július', 'Augusztus', 'Szeptember', 'Október', 'November', 
    'December'];
    var nap = ['V','H','K','Sze','Cs','P','Szo'];
    var currentyear = new Date();
    var ev = currentyear.getFullYear();
    var d = new Date();
    //document.getElementById("napok2").innerHTML = ev + "." +  honap[d.getMonth()];
    var year,last_year,i;
    for (year = ev-1, last_year = ev+1; year<=last_year; year++)
        for (i=0; i<honap.length; i++)
            document.getElementById("napok2").innerHTML += year + "." +  honap[i]+"<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `for` loop like below. `for (let i = ev - 1; i <= ev + 3; i++) {` will loop through `year, last year, and the after 3 years`. And inner `for (let j = 0; j < honap.length; j++)` will loop through all `honap`.

Build required `html` string and use assign it to `napok2`. Use `html.slice(0, -2);` to remove `trailing` `,` .

Check it below.

```js
var honap = ['Január', 'Február', 'Március', 'Április', 'Május', 'Június', 'Július', 'Augusztus', 'Szeptember', 'Október', 'November', 'December'];
var nap = ['V', 'H', 'K', 'Sze', 'Cs', 'P', 'Szo'];
var currentyear = new Date();
var ev = currentyear.getFullYear();
var d = new Date();

let html = "";
for (let i = ev - 1; i <= ev + 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < honap.length; j++) {
    html += i + "." + honap[j] + ", ";
  }
}

document.getElementById("napok2").innerHTML = html.slice(0, -2);
```

```html
<div id='napok2'></div>
```